# Is the Ueno fibration smooth?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, abelian-varieties

Let $A$ be an abelian variety over $\mathbb{C}$ and let $X\subset A$ be a closed subvariety. Let $X\to Y$ be the Ueno fibration. (That is, $Y$ is of general type and a closed subvariety of $A/B$ where $B$ is some abelian subvariety of $A$. Also, the morphism $X\to Y\to A/B$ equals the morphism $X\to A\to A/B$.)

> > Is $X\to Y$ smooth?

> > Are **all** fibres of $X\to Y$ abelian varieties?

> > Is $X\to Y$ a torsor under some abelian scheme?

Comment: Yes to the 3 questions. This is the content of Ueno's Theorem 10.9 in *Classification theory of algebraic varieties and compact complex manifolds*, LNM 439.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

abx answered the question:

"Yes to the 3 questions. This is the content of Ueno's Theorem 10.9 in Classification theory of algebraic varieties and compact complex manifolds, LNM 439"